# How to convert LIGHTGBM to PMML?

Tags: python, pojo, lightgbm, pmml, mojo

I would like to know if there exist a way to convert a LightGBM model to a PMML. Starting from the lightgbm.basic.Booster object I would like to know how to convert it to a PMML or MOJO/POJO object. If is not possible, i would like to know if it is possible to save the LGBM model as Pickle and than convert it to a PMML (or MOJO/POJO) object.

Answer (score 1):

For now, there are at least two ways to create PMML from lightGBM, such as [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) and [Nyoka](https://github.com/SoftwareAG/nyoka), but both cannot create PMML from a learned Booster.

To create PMML, we need to use a Scikit-learn API such as `LGBMClassifier` and Pipeline. Both packages can create PMML in almost the same way. The detailed usage is described in [here](https://openscoring.io/blog/2019/04/07/converting_sklearn_lightgbm_pipeline_pmml/) for sklearn2pmml and [here](https://github.com/SoftwareAG/nyoka/blob/master/examples/lgbm/1_lgbm.ipynb) for Nyoka, and both are pretty simple.

Nyoka just uses the normal Scikit-learn API for training, but sklearn2pmml requires Java to be installed and `PMMLPipeline` to be used during training, so if you are using python and sklearn, Nyoka may be a better choice.

It would be nice if there was a way to create PMML directly from a trained Booster or a way to convert `Booster` to `LGBMClassifier` and then create PMML, but there are no other packages to create PMML from `Booster` directly and according to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1942), there is no official way to convert `Booster` to `LGBMClassifier`.